# pgAdmin 4 COPY fails with "ERROR: missing data for column"

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, csv, pgadmin-4

I am trying to import CSV data to PostgreSQL.

Here is a data sample:

[image]

Here is the command:

`\copy dbo.a (url, price, title, \"ASIN\", ratings, index) FROM 'C:/projects/py/WEBSCR~1/csvtest/Book1.txt' DELIMITER ',' ;`

The error that I get is:

```
ERROR: missing data for column "price"
CONTEXT: COPY a, line 1: "url"
```

There is no null value in the data set. I tried importing a text file, but it still gave me the same error.

Comment: Your CSV file has seven columns, and you've only specified six in the copy command.  I think you may have more issues than that, but for starters ID and align the columns.

Comment: 1) What is the table definition for `dbo.a`? **Add as update to question*. 2) The error also shows that `\copy` is reading the header row.  You need to do: `\copy dbo.a (url, price, title, \"ASIN\", ratings, index) FROM 'C:/projects/py/WEBSCR~1/csvtest/Book1.txt'  WITH (FORMAT CSV HEADER) ;`. The default `delimiter` for `CSV` format is `','` so you don't need to specify it. Using  `HEADER` means the first line is ignored on import. `\copy` is just a `psql` metacommand for [COPY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html) so it would be a good idea to read the section of the docs.

Comment: Did you do this using the `pgAdmin4` Import/Export dialog?

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73914982/edit) (when able). Thanks in advance.